# Passing Presentation Modal objects to the service and business layer

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I am developing a web application using struts2 EJB3(Service/business layer) and Hibernate. I am using Wildfly 10 as a server. Struts is at presentation later, EJB3 at business layer along with simple java classes as Service layer and hibernate is used in persistence later.
Now in one of my action classes I have passed the modal object to the service layer(Simple java classes). Now when I created the EAR and tried to deploy it on the WIldfly. WIldfly refused to start. Then I realised that my ejb module is not able to find the classes of web module. So now I have two ways to resolve this problem:-

1) Either include my web classes in EJB jar:- I think it will completely kill the layered architecture and decoupling of presentation layer and service layer.

2) Or map the modal classes to some other modal classes present in service layer:- It will require to create redundant POJO classes in service layer as well.

Not really know what should I do in this case and if someboddy can suggest me with some better layering structure

Comment: there's no better layering structure. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31783166/573032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are serveral ways you can architect your models for each layer but at the end of the day, it depends on how much you wish to couple each layer with one another.

Obviously the most granular and cleanest solution is to allow each layer to have its own models and to map accordingly at each integration point.

1. Persistence models, e.g. your `@Entity` classes
2. Domain models, e.g. those your service tier takes as input and returns as output.
3. View models, e.g. those your presentation tier takes as input and returns as output.

The advantage of such a distinction is that it allows the models at each level to morph over time without a significant impact to the tiers above it.  In other words, adding a new field or changing something with your persistence model doesn't necessarily mean your domain models must change, but just the mapping code between them.

Obviously there are a number of sources on the internet which advocate simply reusing your `@Entity` classes as the model at each tier and for simple applications, that's definitely acceptable.  But in more complex, scalable solutions that eventually becomes a liability.

Sometimes it's acceptable to collapse (1) and (2) into a single model, the `@Entity` and then use special view models for rendering so at least your view code isn't impacted when you make model changes over-time, but I typically err on the side of using a different model for all three tiers in many cases for complex applications.